# How do I numerically approximate a gradient term?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve a system of differential equations. My question is simple. I am using a discrete approximation for the first and second spatial derivatives in my equations, using the definition of a first and second derivative. The delta h is known. I want to understand the last term of this equation. How can I represent it using numerical approximations for the first and second derivative? I have tried distributing the derivative, however, it leads my model to be uunsolvable I am trying to replicate the results of a modeling paper.

$$
\frac{d N A_{i}}{d t}=-\mu_{N} N A_{i}+\frac{r_{v}\left(z_{i}\right) N A_{B i}}{V_{T}\left(\bar{z}_{i}\right)}-\chi \nabla_{i}\left(N A_{i} \nabla_{i} T N F_{i}\right)
$$

Comment: $\nabla_i=\partial_i$. Use a discrete approximation of the partial derivative.

Comment: I think he is also wondering about the distribution, because there two nabla symbols in the last term.